# adding textViews programatically doesn't print anything

Tags: android

i have three lists with the same number of elements in each other, i want to put first element of all lists in a tablerow, then second element of all lists in another tablerow,
the lists are :

```
competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
                marks = new LinkedList<String>();
                numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();
```

so i use this function:

```
private void addTextViews() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlMarksTable);
        for(int ctr=0;ctr<marks.size();ctr++)
        {
        //Creating new tablerows and textviews
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
        TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
        TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
        TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
        //setting the text
        txt1.setText(competitoinsIDs.get(ctr));
        txt2.setText(marks.get(ctr));
        txt3.setText(numOfQuestions.get(ctr));
        //the textviews have to be added to the row created
        row.addView(txt1);
        row.addView(txt2);
        row.addView(txt3);
        tbl.addView(row);
        }
    }
```

and this is the layout xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tlMarksTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksCompetitionID"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Competition"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksMarks"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Marks"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMarksQuestionsNum"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Questions"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

what am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: Are you sure for loop is being called? Did you check by debugging?

Comment: i don't know how to debug , would u tell me please?

Comment: @tottiroma In this case you could use Log.d(String tag, String message) inside the loop. This would print something at the logcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set proper `LayoutParams` on the `TableRows` and `TextView` that you add to the layout:

```
private void addTextViews() {
        TableLayout tbl=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlMarksTable);
        for(int ctr=0;ctr<marks.size();ctr++) {
            TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
            TableLayout.LayoutParams tlp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams text1lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams text2lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams text3lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 

            txt1.setText(competitoinsIDs.get(ctr));
            txt1.setLayoutParams(text1lp);
            txt2.setText(marks.get(ctr));
            txt2.setLayoutParams(text2lp);
            txt3.setText(numOfQuestions.get(ctr));
            txt3.setLayoutParams(text3lp);
            row.addView(txt1);
            row.addView(txt2);
            row.addView(txt3);
            row.setLayoutParams(tlp);
            tbl.addView(row);
        }
}
```

This is assuming that your data lists aren't empty.

Comment: still nothing print on the screen , and i am sure the lists is not empty becuase i print it

Comment: @tottiroma Are you sure the `addTextViews` method is being called?

Comment: @tottiroma Yes, you must use it, I forgot to add it in my code. I've edited the answer.

Comment: i will check , sorry for being late , the internet is slowly

Comment: it seems that the lists was empyt so i put it on `oncreate` like this, competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
  marks = new LinkedList<String>();
  numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();
  competitoinsIDs.add("4");
  marks.add("2");
  numOfQuestions.add("4");
  addTextViews();
but i got exception null pointer,

Comment: @tottiroma In the logcat, see at which line do you get the `NullPointerException`. I doubt is from those lists so it's from other parts of your code.

Comment: this is the activity, it is very small, would u check it please http://www.mediafire.com/?t6jucp3bc4fi0l2

Comment: @tottiroma You don't set the content view in the activity so when you search for the `TableLayout` it returns `null`. In the `onCreate` method set the content view with `setContentView(R.layout.layout_containing_the_tablelayout);`(the layout file from your question?!?!) after the line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: OMG ,i forget it, sorry , big sorry, i will try

Comment: yes it works , thank you i accept the answer, but please would you see how it looks, it has to but each value under each lable http://www.mediafire.com/?z443loocl171kuh

Comment: @tottiroma Your first `TableRow` has some padding set on it in the xml layout so you should set the same padding on the `TableRow` that you create in code(use the method `setPadding` on `row`). Also, remove the `weightSum` and the `layout_weight` attributes from the first row and set `android:stretchColumns="*"` on your `TableLayout` if you want equal width columns.

Answer (score 1):

ADD as TableRow and TextView To `TableLayout` :

```
for(int ctr=0;ctr<marks.size();ctr++)
        {       
       //YOUR CODE....
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txt1=new TextView(this);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txt2=new TextView(this);
        txt1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView txt3=new TextView(this);
        txt3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //YOUR CODE....
    }
```

Comment: oh ur answer is like the previus answer ,and doesn't print any  thing on screen :(

Comment: @tottiroma :what do you mean by previus answer i give you answer first ok and make sure you are calling addTextViews method for adding rows

Comment: this is my oncreate competitoinsIDs = new LinkedList<String>();
  marks = new LinkedList<String>();
  numOfQuestions = new LinkedList<String>();
  competitoinsIDs.add("4");
  marks.add("2");
  numOfQuestions.add("4");
  addTextViews(); 
i got null pointer exception, thank you

Comment: i didn't knew that u was the first, sorry